# Groovy constructors and bean initialization performance

Tags: groovy

What is the difference between the following groovy initializations:

```
def valuesMap = [:]

// method 1
def myBeanInstance1 = new MyBean()
myBeanInstance1.properties = valuesMap 

// method 2
def myBeanInstance2 = new MyBean(valuesMap)
```

I observe that these 2 perform very differently

Comment: I am guessing one makes reflection calls to make the assignments and the other queries the MetaProperty of the class to find the data types and make the assignments. That's why i see method 1 to be faster than method 2 (which makes reflection calls).

Comment: How much faster? Is it really significant enough to worry about?

Comment: Plus w.r.t groovy beans, `method 1` would fail when it tries to set the `class` property of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

myBeanInstance1.properties = valuesMap  is illegal because properties is read only.

Method 2 basically invoked a constructor Groovy inject where it'll set attributes by reflection matching map keys with attribute names.